# Criteria Many-to-Many With Custom Join Table Domain

Tags: grails, many-to-many, grails-orm, criteria-api

Given the following example domains:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {
  User user
  Role role
}

class User { 
  Set<Role> getRoles() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
  } 
}

class Role { 
  Set<User> getUsers() {
    UserRole.findAllByRole(this).collect { it.user } as Set
}
```

I can't figure out how to build the criteria to find all the users with a given role.  I tried the following:

```
def crit = User.createCriteria()
def results = crit.list {
  roles {
    eq('authority', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
  }
}
```

However, it says it can't find the property 'roles' in User.  The reason I need a criteria for this is because there will be additional properties in User being searched on so dynamic finders won't work for this situation.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result, and how large do you expect it to be?

Comment: I ask because I'm wondering if querying `UserRole` and `.collect{}`ing the Users off of it is an option.

Comment: The results are going to be pretty small.  However, there are other associations that need to be queried off of user directly as well.  Other Many-to-Many associations, assuming it is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your expected result is small, it's probably easy enough to just do this:

```
def c = UserRole.createCriteria()
def users = c.list {
    role {
        eq('authority', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    }
    user {
        // additional user property constraints
    }
}.collect { it.user }
```

If you expect a large set of results, or you need to page over them, I'm not as certain. I'll throw this out there, but I've never tried it. I don't know if you can use `projections { property('association') }` and have it work.

```
def c = UserRole.createCriteria()
def users = c.list {
    projections {
        property('user') // never tried this, but worth a shot
    }
    role {
        eq('authority', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    }
    user {
        // additional user property constraints
    }
}
```

I don't think what you're trying to do in your example will work, since you don't actually have relationships defined on your `User` or `Role` classes that reference the `UserRole` (i.e. with a `hasMany`).

Comment: You can shorten that first one up slightly by replacing `}.collect { it.user }` with just `}.user` since the result is a List.

Comment: Would I need a `}*.user`, or will `}.user` itself work? I've never seen the latter syntax used.

Comment: @Burt - Also, you're probably the one to ask: Will the `projection` in the second example work? I've never tried it. I'll set up a quick test myself if you don't know off the top of your head.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  That makes perfect sense.  The only problem is some of the other search criteria is from other many-to-many associations.  UserAddress, for example.  If it is possible to build a criteria with this model.  So like "userrole == foo && useraddress.city == bar && firstName like doo."

Comment: @Rob - sorry, I'm terrible at criteria queries - I always use HQL. Easy enough to test though :)

Comment: @Burt - np, I'll run a test myself. I'm pretty curious about this, actually.

Comment: @Rob I tried your last example and it doesn't work.  Darn!  That was good thinking.  Too bad.  I might be stuck either reverting to HQL directly (which sucks because things are conditional) or performing multiple queries then discarding/combining data in code (blech).

Comment: Ok - I'll remove that one; it was mostly just a suggestion to try. If it were me, I'd probably just do the first one, since it's straightforward, and will work for a small amount of users (if you don't need paging and can afford to load them all into memory). It's not the most elegant way, but it will work. You can prune down the resulting list with your other association queries afterward. Again, not the prettiest. But 15-minutes of coding and a couple of loops might serve you better than spending a day building that perfect criteria query.

Comment: @Rob, yep, that's what I'm thinking also.  Thanks.